# New Instagram Enforce signed request vs signed headers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, instagram, instagram-api

Recently Instagram has implemented signed requests https://instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/. I own a website that has thousands of users making api requests, I currently use signed headers and am getting 100 likes/hour and 60 relationships/hour, which is the highest.

My question is, is it necessary to sign both the header and the request, or is the header enough? And what would be the benefits to signing both, Instagram does not really specify this.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My app only signs the header and gets the higher limit (100 likes/hour) so I don't think signing the request too is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Actualy they told that this method of signing only the header will be deprecated on September 1th 2015. So you will have to implement this incremental change!

http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests#notes